# When we get this particular Error: "Type Error: Cannot unpack non-iterable int object"?

Tags: python

I get the following error, "cannot unpack non-iterable int object," when attempting to run the following code:

```
def sum_defi(a,b):
    return a+b
    return a-b
a,b = sum_defi(5,4)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Error**: `TypeError:cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

First thing, we can't write multiple return statements. But what does this particular error mean?

Comment: You can't have two return statements, so the second return is completely ignored and never seen. Your assignment statement is trying to unpack a tuple, but an int is being returned.

Comment: Well, you can, it’s just that only one will execute.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are trying to unpack the results of the function, which is an integer, into two variables a & b.

The unpacking syntax is used to assign values from an iterable object to variables in a single line. Ex., if you have a tuple (x, y) and you want to assign its values to variables a and b, you can use the unpacking syntax like this: a, b = (x, y).

Try this:

```
def sum_defi(a,b):
    return a+b, a-b

result = sum_defi(5, 4)
a, b = result
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns only one value while you try to assign two

Comment: The code never comes to the second return

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You may use yield in place of return but not much-recommended style:

```
def sum_defi(a,b):
    yield a+b
    yield a-b
print(a)
print(b)
```

To return a tuple and unpack it:

```
def sum_defi(a,b):
    return a+b, a-b # Function ends here
    # Any statement here (below ONE return statement) won't be executed
a,b = sum_defi(5,4)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can have many `return` statements. Its just that the first one executed returns control to the calling code and the function is complete. In your case, the first `return` means the second is not executed. You can get a feel for what your program does by printing its return value without making any assumptions about what that value is.

```
def sum_defi(a,b):
    return a+b
    return a-b
    
print(sum_defi(5,4))
```

prints the single integer

```
9
```

You were attempting to unpack a collection into the two variables `a` and `b`. But the function returned a single `int`, not a collection of two integers. The function returned one thing, you wanted two things, and thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code is that it attempts to unpack a single return value into two variables, which causes a TypeError.

To fix this, you could modify the sum_defi function to return a tuple containing both the sum and the difference of a and b, like this:

```
 def sum_defi(a, b):
     return a + b, a - b
```

Then, you can unpack the tuple returned by the function into two variables like this:

```
result = sum_defi(5, 4)
a, b = result
print(a)
print(b)
```

This will print 9 for a (the sum of 5 and 4) and 1 for b (the difference between 5 and 4).